# Cors and database uri problem in scaling out architecture

Tags: mongodb, docker, spring-boot, kubernetes, cors

I have react frontend and spring boot backend with mongodb behind.

I have issues with setting 2 parameters in the spring boot service.

First is address of the mongodb which is now set as localhost:27017 in the application.properties
It works at localhost but since I plan to scale out  using kubernetes and docker images i would like to know how to define
It and where for the case in which I have mongo1 mongo2 and mongo3 database hosts and would like to pass all 3 URIs ?

Second issues is more tricky! React frontend doesnt work in chrome until I put allow cross origin anotation over my spring rest endpoint . I used hardcoded localhost:3000 here but when I scale it out using kubernetes this wont work if it gets data from another host in the cluster.What to do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "another host in the cluster"?  Presumably you have everything routed through an ingress, with a domain name that you control?

Answer (score 2):

1. To answer your first question, you can configure multi data sources, see here documentation how you can configure more than one data sources ([80.2 Configure Two DataSources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html).
2. For second question you can simply wildcard `CORS URL` or if you know all of your front end server urls which are load balanced you can pass as list of cors url.

   ```
   – * – means that all origins are allowed.

   – If undefined, all origins are allowed.
   ```

**RECOMMENDATION**

Run your react via `yarn` to deploy on `Apache` or `ngnix`. Once you seted up your domain or sub domain for front end, load balanced your front end so not required to run your front end on ports..